# Express.js Popup windows

Tags: node.js, express, popupwindow

1 . Is there any Express.js middleware to show as popup up windows (e.g meteor has ) ?

2 .  How res.render to popup windows instead of .ejs or .jade full page ?

Comment: This way to broad a question.  You are going to have to dig in a bit on you own.

Comment: Study HTML and JS! That's all you need. This has nothing to do with node.js or express.